# SPL routine is no longer valid

Tags: stored-procedures, informix

I have a stored procedure named

```
"component_allocate"
```

When I execute this procedure using PreparedStatement, I get the following error

```
[Error Code: -721, SQL State: IX000]  SPL routine(AAABxg) is no longer valid.
```

I get the same error even when I execute the procedure directly on DbVisualizer.

I tried updating the statistics on the procedure using

```
update statistics for procedure component_allocate
```

That didn't help. Still getting the same error.

Has anyone else faced this problem in informix ? How do I resolve this?

Comment: Can you clarify 'using PreparedStatement'?  I guess you call this from some programming language?  Does the routine executes using plain sql?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this?

"If an index was added after the statement was prepared, you must prepare the statement again and declare the cursor again. You cannot simply reopen the cursor if it was based on a prepared statement that is no longer valid."

source: 
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.docnotes.doc/uc3/ids_perf_docnotes_10.0.html